# With Supabase and SvelteKit, I'm getting an empty array with RLS even with policy

Tags: sveltekit, supabase

I have a client table an want to allow the users to see only the clients they created.

I enabled RLS and created a policy, but I'm getting an empty array when querying the data.

In Supabase Studio, when I select authenticated role and impersonate a user, I can see the clients this user created.

I followed the Supabase documentation for SvelteKit:

[SvelteKit Web App Demo](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-sveltekit)

The only thing I didn't implement was PKCE.

This is my policy:

```sql
create policy "Allow users to select only the clients they created"
on client for select
to authenticated
using (
  auth.uid() = "userId"
)
```

The column `userId` has a relation with `auth.users.id`.

This is my query:

```js
export const readAllClients = async () => {
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("client")
    .select("*, invoice(id, invoiceStatus, lineItems(*))");

  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }

  // Puts the data in a Svelte writable store called clients
  clients.set(data as Client[]);
};
```

Setting the role to `anon` and `using` to `true`, returns data normally.

Comment: Sounds to me that your policy is wrong, try removing the quotes in `userId` in your policy. It sounds like you're comparing `auth.uid()` to the string "userId" and not actually the client's `userId`.

Comment: @moonstar-x If I do that it understands it as `userid`. If I log the session on both client and server, I get the data back, including the user id.

Comment: I don't think I understood what happens when using `userId` directly. Is it acting as if no policy was created in the first place?

Comment: What if you remove the role filter `to authenticated` to have it apply to all `public` roles?

Comment: @moonstar-x Same thing. I think the problem is not with RLS, because when I login the session is passed to the application, but when my store function calls Supabase, the session is `null`.

Comment: It seems like the authorization header is not going through to Supabase, but we will need to see more of your project to see what could be wrong.